# Vscode settings problems

Tags: css, json, visual-studio-code, settings

So I'm editing my settings in JSON and it all works well but this error keeps popping up:
"Expected comma jsonc(514)"
This is my code:
["css.lint.emptyRules": "ignore",](https://i.stack.imgur.com/455nv.png)

This is the whole json file just in case:
[Whole Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClQLp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after the "gitlens.advanced.messages" object and before "css.lint.emptyRules": "ignore". That should solve your issue, also I highly advise you to take a look here [JSON Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I missed a comma. Well, it seems like I need to improve my debugging skills.